# Swift, Xcode and Windows Service Layer

Tags: c#, ios, xcode, swift, visual-studio

Is it at all possible to integrate a native iOS app developed in Xcode with a Service Layer developed with Visual Studio?

Comment: did you mean a dll or a web api?

Comment: We're creating a Data Access Layer, so I presume we are using asp.net and creating a web api.

Comment: In that case you can use Alamofire to make network request to connect from iOS apps to webapi https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire also with https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON for parsing json objects

Comment: You have to be more clear. Do yo want to use 'your code or dlls' or only want to access data layer? - if so you can use .NET Web API and on the client side network frameworks such as [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) or [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)